# awk: printing FILENAME once when criteria are met several times in a file

Tags: if-statement, awk, criteria

I Have a series of files and would like to know which ones meet a certain criteria (egs. $1 == "ice" && $2 == "cream"). This criterion is met several times in the same file. I would like awk to print the filename once when this criterion is met.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (nextfile is a GNU extension):

```
awk '$1=="ice" && $2=="cream"{print FILENAME;nextfile}'  file1 file2 file3
```

Or if you don't have GNU:

```
awk 'FNR==1{p=0} $1=="ice" && $2=="cream" && !p {print FILENAME;p=1}'  file1 file2 file3
```

The `FNR==1` resets the `p` flag at the start of each file, and then when your criteria are met, the `p` flag gets set to `1` so the filename only comes out once.

By the way, you may prefer the simplicity of this:

```
grep -l "^ice.*cream" file*
```

It is not identical, but pretty similar.

**EDITED AFTER ACCEPTANCE**

This is another possibility that may be more elegant. It saves the names of matching files in an array `names[]` and prints the keys of the array `names[]` at the end.

```
awk '$1=="ice" && $2=="cream" {names[FILENAME]++} END{for(i in names)print i}'
```

Comment: `exit` here will do that it will only print the first filename it find with hits. If he like all files with `ice` and `cream` it will fail.  Using the regex in grep, will fail if line has `cream` before `ice`

Comment: The second version with `END` section only prints the last file if hits are in multiple files.

Comment: @Jotne I am assuming he has ice before cream because he checks for ice in $1 and cream in $2.

Comment: You are correct, but the grep will also give hits for this line `my cold ice cream`

Comment: Indeed! That's why I said it is "pretty similar".

Comment: If you could add an anchor to your grep to make it hit from beginning of the line, it will be better, see my awk example.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do

```
awk '$1 == "ice" && $2 == "cream" {print FILENAME}' *
```

To get line number and line info, you can use:

```
awk '$1 == "ice" && $2 == "cream"  {print NR,$0,"->",FILENAME}' *
```

Another version:

```
awk '/^ice cream/ {print NR,$0,"->",FILENAME}' *
```